# How to gather the name of the files in each subdirectory into a text file in that subdirectory?

Tags: shell, shell-script, files

I wanted to save the names of all files in each sub directory into a text file in that sub directory,
so I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for X in "$PWD" *
do  
    if [ -d "$X" ];
    then
        cd "$X"
        files="$(ls)"
        echo "$files" >> filesNames.txt
    fi
done
```

but, I cannot enter sub directories using:

```
cd "$X"
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What error message do you see?

Comment: Why do you quote all the uses of variables but not do `cd "$X"`? If there is a space in the directory name then `cd` will not work

Comment: @JigglyNaga Nothing, it produces filesnames.txt file containing the name of sub directories in the parent directory.

Comment: @Anthon, I checked it. No difference, still generates the same unexpected result.

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, each suddir contains thousands of png files.

Comment: You've forgotten to `cd ..` back out of each subdirectory after processing it.  So the `if [ -d "$X" ]` test fails, hence you seeing no error messages.

Comment: @JigglyNaga still, no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comments, you only have to descend one level deep. In that case you could use a glob to iterate over directories names and for each dir save file paths in an array, then print the last element of each path to `fileNames.txt`:

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in "$PWD"/*/; do
arr=( "$dir"* )
printf %s\\n "${arr[@]##*/}" > "$dir"filesNames.txt
done
```

To exclude symlinks just add a condition e.g. `if [[ ! -L "${dir%?}" ]]; then arr...`

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much and thank you all!

Comment: Replace `"${arr[@]##*/}"` with `"${arr[@]}"` if you need the full paths to your files. Also, add `shopt -s dotglob` at the top if you need to select hidden (dot) files too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `cd` out of each subdirectory before trying the next one.  Inserting...

```
cd ..
```

at the end of the loop would fix this for the subdirectories, but breaks when you do it in the top directory first.  A `cd ..` from there will take you up another level, so the other directories aren't visible any more.

You can address all of this by saving the top directory in a variable, and `cd` to there each time:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOPDIR="$PWD"
for X in "$PWD" * ; 
do
        if [ -d "$X" ] ;
        then
                cd "$X"
                files="$(ls)"
                echo "$files" >> filesNames.txt
                cd "$TOPDIR"
        fi
done
```

You might also want to change `>>` to `>`, if you don't want to keep all the results from previous runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for X in $PWD/* ; do
        if [ -d "$X" ] ; then # first depth directories
                cd "$X" ;
                files="$(ls)" ;
                printf "$files\n" >> filesNames.txt ;
        else # regular files:
                printf "$X\n" >> fileNames.txt ;
        fi ;
done ;
```

It may be that what you are trying to achieve can generalised using `find` - using additional options (`man find`) for each `$X` - such as:

```
files=$(find ${PWD} -type f) ;
printf "$files\n" >> filesNames.txt ;
```

Comment: This prints all names into a single file at the top.  The OP requires a text file in each subdirectory.

Comment: So in the first example prefix the piped output with the current "$X" path eg: `printf "$files\n" >> $X/filesNames.txt ;`

Comment: @aphorise Thanks, it is a nice suggestion, but:

1. the result still will be saved in the parent directory

2. It contains the name of all subdirs, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c "cd {} ; ls | grep -v '^filesNames.txt$' > filesNames.txt" \;
```

This finds all directories beneath the current directory and, for each one, it `cd`s into the directory and writes the directory listing to a `filesNames.txt` (excluding that file from the list).

If you want the `filesNames.txt` files to be in the lists too, remove the `| grep -v ...` from the command:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c "cd {} ; ls > filesNames.txt" \;
```