# find my misunderstanding about this little piece of shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, pwd

Actually, I have a folder which contains several sub folders with lots of images in each.

I am trying to gather all the names of the files in each sub folder in a text file (filesNames.txt) in that sub folder in the form of:

**Absolute/path/to/each/file**/filename

So, I wrote an script in the parent folder:

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in "$PWD"/*/; do
arr=( "$dir"* )
cd "$dir"
printf "%s 1\n" "$PWD/${arr[@]##*/}" > "$dir"filesNames.txt
cd ..
done
```

**My problem** is that:

I have the absolute address just for the first file in each sub folder.
For the rest there is only filenames without absolute address:

```
 /run/media/parent_folder/subfolder/filename1.png
 filename2.png
 filename3.png
 ...
```

I think it is related to **$PWD** variable which I iterate over it just once for each sub folder. How can I change the script in a suitable form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @don_crissti To have sub folder names in the printed absolute path of each file.

Comment: Why didn't you say you need full paths ? Just replace `${arr[@]##*/}"` in my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284135)  with `"${arr[@]}"`

Comment: @don_crissti You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single `find` command will output all the files with absolute path

```
find $(pwd) -type f
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to do that using pure shell script and dont want to use find, try this little one:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Simple bash recursive loop search - Luciano A. Martini =) 
nextdir(){
for f in *; do 
   if [ -d "$f" ] && [ ! -L "$f" ]; then
        #echo "Inside folder: $PWD/$f"
        nextdir "$f"
        cd ..
        continue
   else
        echo "$PWD/$f"
   fi
done 
}
#call the function for the first time...
nextdir
```

Save for example as recursive-loop and execute in the folder you want to do the search. 
It will do exactly what the find or other recursive mechanisms does, but using a for loop, and you can customize for your needs!

```
$./recursive-loop
/home/luciano/readme.txt
/home/luciano/images/a.bmp
/home/luciano/texts/a.txt
/home/luciano/texts/b.txt
/home/luciano/texts/music/lyrics.txt
(...)
```